# Python WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selnium Python but I got error says "WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable"
I know it's because of incompatibility between Chrome and chromedriver, but I make sure I downloaded chromedrive according to my current Chrom version and put them in the same directory

Chrome: 99.0.4844.51(64bit)
Selenium: 4.1.2

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                             
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.melon.com')
```

error saying:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp/ipykernel_6900/3465716408.py in <module>
----> 1 driver.get('https://www.melon.com')
      2 # time.sleep(2) #2초간 정지

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    435         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    436         """
--> 437         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    438 
    439     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    423         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    424         if response:
--> 425             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    426             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    427                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 
    249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x008C9943+2595139]
    Ordinal0 [0x0085C9F1+2148849]
    Ordinal0 [0x007543F0+1065968]
    Ordinal0 [0x007487C2+1017794]
    Ordinal0 [0x00748FF8+1019896]
    Ordinal0 [0x0074A892+1026194]
    Ordinal0 [0x00744219+999961]
    Ordinal0 [0x00755860+1071200]
    Ordinal0 [0x007AB2D2+1422034]
    Ordinal0 [0x0079B806+1357830]
    Ordinal0 [0x00776086+1204358]
    Ordinal0 [0x00776F96+1208214]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A6B232+1658114]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B2312C+2411516]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095F261+560433]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095E366+556598]
    Ordinal0 [0x0086286B+2173035]
    Ordinal0 [0x008675F8+2192888]
    Ordinal0 [0x008676E5+2193125]
    Ordinal0 [0x008711FC+2232828]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7656FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x771C7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x771C7A6E+238]
```

Comment: Do you have `chromedriver` in your `PATH`?

Comment: yes it's in the same directory

Comment: I just sovled the problem with creating python file like **.py instead of **.ipynb. but I was wondering why it didn't work at Jupyter file